# Champion that can jump like Tristana in League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends

I love to use Tristana jump onto an enemy to attack and jump away from them to retreat.

I wonder if there is any champion who have the ability to jump like her?

p.s.

My [google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=champion%20that%20can%20jump%20like%20tristana) shows me this result but it seems the users list a lot of names. Which is correct actually?

Comment: It would be helpful to elaborate on exactly what you're looking for in a "jumping" character--are you looking for other marksmen/ADCs who have the ability to quickly get in and out of fights, or just any character who has a movement ability? This page also might help you: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Dash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the closest "relative" to Tristanas jump is [Kha'Zix](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kha'Zix) evolved Leap:

- Similar Range
- Resets on kill/asisst

The closest ADC is probably Corki, since he has a similar range, but no reset.

Comment: What does ADC mean?

Comment: AD = Attack damage, meaning basic damage done by auto attacks and abilities, as well as some items. ADC = Attack Damage Carry, meaning a champion that usually has low health but deals a lot of damage from auto attacks, or attack damage.

Comment: @NamGVU Attack Damage Carry. Its a role  in LoL which is supposed to deal a lot of physical damage from range.

Answer (score 2):

does it have to be a jump or do other kinds of jumplike skills count?

real jumps are on:

- aatrox (no reset)
- kha zix
- gnar (no reset)
- nidalee (resets by hunting a target not by kills)
- shyvana (long cd though since its the ult)
- zac (has a windup though)

for jumplike skills there a rang of champs so i wont list them all, only adcs that can deal dmg with them, none of them has a reset:

- caitlyn with her net
- corki
- ezreal

Comment: Most of those don't have reset.

Comment: what about katarina?

Comment: @ItaySela altough it does reset it is not a jump, but a blink.

Comment: she can only jump to something not on free trrain thats why i left her out

Comment: A proposed edit suggests you may have missed `rengar (only during ultimate or in bush)`